# XSD Error with Annotation tag during Validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am attempting to include Annotations in a schema, and it seems that it's causing issues during Validation. I'm receiving an error of:

> "Validation [schema building by Format exception]: s4s-elt-must-match.1: The >content of 'Amount' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, >(unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: annotation."

As far as I can tell, my schema is correct, as is the XML. I've validated both are well formed, and in both Visual Studio as well as online Schema checkers, both are well-formed and valid.

I'm using a small-ish software which is Java based.

If I remove the  tag, it validates properly, so it seems that it's something surrounding that. I'm not entirely sure that it's my XML or the software that I'm using that's causing the issue, but I'd prefer to keep the  for documentation purposes.

I've included both the XML and XSD below. These are short examples, representative of the actual XML and XSD, which are proprietary and contain PHI.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:Root xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <ns2:Fruit>Apple</ns2:Fruit>
    <ns2:Amount>3</ns2:Amount>
</ns2:Root>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Fruit" type="Fruit_Type"/>
        <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:int">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
              Amount of Fruit
            </xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="Fruit_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Testing
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value = "Apple"/>
      <xs:enumeration value = "Banana"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Works for me. I don't think there's anything wrong in the XSD/XML. It's either a very odd bug in your schema processor, or it's something to do with the way you are running it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll report it to the software creators.